# Changing the image for a Twitter card page?

Tags: twitter-card

After the Twitter spider has already scanned your page, and it's been shared a few times; is it possible to change the twitter card image, tags, URL (Google Analytics params, mainly `utm_content`) and text, so that when it is shared again it won't be the same ad that was shared before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the image is cached for about a week before the spider visits again.

More here - https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting

Comment: Since links are often broken, SE generally asks for a run-down of the answer on the target page. Can you explain how to change the image for future users?